# I want to retrieve two different names from table 1 based on two different fields in table 2?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "phonebook" and "phonecall" and I want to look up names in the phonebook based on the callFrom and callTo.

My code returns the same name for both as I'm only referencing the callTo field and unable to include the callFrom field.

```
SELECT 
    phonecall.callDate, 
    phonecall.callTime, 
    phonecall.callFrom, 
    phonebook.personFirstname as First, 
    phonebook.personLastname as Last, 
    phonecall.callTo, phonebook.personFirstname First1, 
    phonebook.personLastname as Last1, 
    phonecall.callDuration
FROM phonecall 
LEFT JOIN phonebook on 
    callTo = phonebook.personService
WHERE 1
ORDER BY phonecall.callDate, phonecall.callTime
```

This code fails:

```
SELECT 
    phonecall.callDate, 
    phonecall.callTime, 
    phonecall.callFrom, 
    phonebook.personFirstname as First, 
    phonebook.personLastname as Last, 
    phonecall.callTo, 
    phonebook.personFirstname as First1, 
    phonebook.personLastname as Last1, 
    phonecall.callDuration
FROM phonecall 
LEFT JOIN phonebook on 
    phonecall.callTo = phonebook.personService
LEFT JOIN phonebook on 
    phonecall.callFrom = phonebook.personService
WHERE 1
ORDER BY phonecall.callDate, phonecall.callTime
```

I know it's probably very simple but I've very limited SQL experience and haven't found any examples.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: You need to add an alias to each of the two joins, the use that to tell the difference between the call from and call to phone book entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but just something to illustrate how you can join the same table twice on different conditions, then return columns from each.

```
SELECT 
    phonecall.callDate, 
    phonecall.callTime, 
    phonecall.callFrom, 
    `callfr`.personFirstname as First, 
    `callfr`.personLastname as Last, 
    phonecall.callTo, 
    `callto`.personFirstname as First1, 
    `callto`.personLastname as Last1, 
    phonecall.callDuration
FROM phonecall 
LEFT JOIN phonebook `callto`
    on phonecall.callTo = `callto`.personService
LEFT JOIN phonebook `callfr`
    on phonecall.callFrom = `callto`.personService
WHERE 1
ORDER BY phonecall.callDate, phonecall.callTime
```

Comment: Thanks Sloan, you're first hint got me across the line after a few failed attempts.Greatly appreciate the help and the sample as well which I'll have a close look at.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it put you on the right track.

Comment: I didn't use the " ` " in my code which worked without problem but is this something that could come back to bite me in a different situation?

Comment: Yes it could be a problem. I've developed the habit of quoting all db, table and column names with backtics just to avoid any issues. If you have a column whose name is a reserved word, it can be difficult to find sometimes if you don't use the backticks.